# SBS 2008 BPA Warnings After Migration From SBS 2003

Tags: domain-name-system, migration, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

We just finished a we-know-just-enough-to-be-dangerous migration from SBS 2003 to SBS 2008, and things seem to have gone relatively smoothly. After running the SBS 2008 Best Practices Analyzer on the destination server, we've got three warning messages, and I can't tell if they're important or not.

First, the easy one:

- `SMTP Port (TCP 25 Status): The Edgetransport.exe process should listen on SMTP port 25, but that port is owned by the  process.` I don't think that this one is a big deal--e-mail is flowing through the SMTP connector. Since there are two spaces between "the" and "process," I'm assuming that for some reason BPA just couldn't figure out the owning process name and this is just some sloppy programming when displaying the message. (Indeed, on subsequent runs of the BPA this message goes away, and other times it comes back.)

Now, two more scary sounding ones:

- `No DNS name server records: There are no DNS name server (NS) resource records in the _msdcs sub-domain in the forward lookup zone for Windows SBS 2008.`

and, similarly,

- `No DNS name server records: There are no DNS name server (NS) resource records in the _msdcs zone for Windows SBS 2008.`

Now for these two, everything *appears* to be functioning correctly--but I'm assuming this is a weird state as a result of the SBS 2003 to 2008 migration. Can anyone provide any pointers on how to fix it, or whether or not it can be safely ignored? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The scary DNS zone warnings are often caused by a migration. The _msdcs zone needs to be replicated to all DNS servers in the entire AD forest and therefore should be a separate zone rather than child entries of the root zone. Of course, since SBS doesn't support forests this shouldn't matter in the slightest.

In theory you can delete the child entries, recreate _msdcs as its own zone, and run ipconfig /registerdns on all DCs to repopulate the zone.

Answer (score 0):

You might try running the CITW (Connect to the Internet Wizard) in the SBS console under Network.  And also FMN (Fix My Network).  This will scan for problems and fix them.

I have your DNS problem in mind but it could fix the Exchange problem as well.  Then rerun the BPA.

Also, I recommend [The Official SBS Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/default.aspx);  they have had some posts on the SBS BPA and there are a few known issues with it, though I haven't heard of the ones you describe.